# how connect to socket in swift to read data and write it

Tags: sockets, swift

how to create a socket in swift that listen to and write on it? Is GCDAsyncSocket a right way or another way is possible? I used CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost to connect to socket but can not read data from.

Comment: in iOS or OS X?  Do you want the socket to be open and listening for connections, or are you connecting to an existing host and just want to do bi-directional communication?

Comment: in ios, I want socket to connect to existing host, send data and listeninig for incoming message.

Comment: What about just listening for connections @JeremyPope ? (for OS X, objecitve-C) I'm trying with `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` but no success, only 'failed to establish connection'(exactly this one: `Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"` without http & `Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}` with "http:/localhost") (host: `@"localhost"` tried with `@"http://localhost"` either different error but no success as well)

Comment: This thread is rather old, but for anyone coming here looking for an up-to-date Swift socket package this might be what you want: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket

Comment: Another possibility is this one: https://github.com/Balancingrock/SwifterSockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SocketRocket ObjC framework bridged to Swift

https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

Then you just create an instance of the class and use it in Swift, i.e.:

```
var socket = SRWebSocket(...)
socket.open()
socket.send()
socket.close()
```

[image: SocketRocket sources]

As the user requested I'm attaching the screenshot of the bridging header prompt:
[image]

Also remember to link your app against libcucore.dylib:
[image]

Comment: Of course I use it every day in my iOS apps. I wouldn't suggest it to you if it didn't.

Comment: after add this framework to "Link Binary with libraries", what should I have to do?help me.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do that, just add the files in a folder and use them. I'll post a screenshot in the Answer.

Comment: thanks, where I have to set ip Address and port of my host?and what is inside of socket-bridging-header.h file?

Comment: It's a file automatically created by Xcode when you compile with ObjC code the first time.

Comment: You should read the SocketRocket documentation to use it but here's how I init the socket with the URL of the host I connect to: You create a NSURLRequest: `var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://host.com"))` then init the socket with it `socket = SRWebSocket(URLRequest: urlRequest)`

Comment: I have just confused!! I run the project but It dosen't create socket-bridging-header.h file.

Comment: When you imported the .m and .h classes to your Swift project Xcode should prompt you with an alert, I'm attaching a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Try creating an Objective-C class from `File > New...` and copy/paste the code of SocketRocket inside of it.

Comment: Yes,it works, But now I have this error in my project.Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:

      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in SRWebSocket.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to link your app against: libcucore.dylib: https://i.imgur.com/WeRmyL0.png

Comment: thank you very much,it fixes my error, One more question, what is input parameter of send method? I want to send a string.

Comment: socket.send("stringMessage") the send() input param is anything you want it to be. Something the socket accepts. Could be a String could be a data stream an Int, anything based on the socket you're connecting to.

Comment: i used this method,but get error. what should I have to do?the error is: Invalid state: cannot call send: until connection is open

Comment: @user2056962 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: excuse me,I forgot that, thank you so much for your information

Comment: after you init the socket, you need to .open() it before you can send information through it. use `socket.open()` before `socket.send()`.

Comment: however i used open before send,i have error! also how I can read data from socket?

Comment: You need to learn the Framework before using it, please read the documentation, you have to implement the Delegate and use the function `func webSocketDidOpen(webSocket: SRWebSocket!)` to check if there are any errors during the connection.

Comment: I implement delegate, but the function webSocketDidOpen was'nt called, do you have any idea?

Comment: Most of these issues are totally different subject from your initial question. You should start a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are interested for a Swift 3 implementation.
It's referenced heavily from [raywenderlich's example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157128/real-time-communication-streams-tutorial-ios#comments) with some edits.

```
func connect() {
    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: self.address!, port: self.port!, inputStream: &self.inputStream, outputStream: &self.outputStream);

    guard let _ = inputStream, let _ = outputStream else {
        // your own execption or otherwise
        return;
    }

    self.inputStream?.delegate = self;
    self.outputStream?.delegate = self;

    self.inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode);
    self.outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode);

    self.inputStream?.open();
    self.outputStream?.open();
}

func disconnect() {
    if let stream = self.inputStream {
        stream.close();
        stream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes);
    }
    if let stream = self.outputStream {
        stream.close();
        stream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes);
    }
    self.inputStream = nil;
    self.outputStream = nil;
}

func write(data:Data) {
    let _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { (unsafePointer:UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
        let bytesWritten = self.outputStream?.write(unsafePointer, maxLength: data.count);
    };
}

func readAvailableBytes(stream: InputStream) {
    var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxReadLength);
    while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
        let numberOfBytesRead = stream.read(buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)
        if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
            if let _ = stream.streamError {
                break
            }
        }
        //Construct the Message object
        if(numberOfBytesRead > 0){
            let output = String(cString:buffer)
            NSLog("server said: %@", output)
        } else {
            NSLog("empty string from stream")
        }

    }
    buffer.deallocate(capacity: maxReadLength);
}
```

And be sure to implement **StreamDelegate** and the delegate method in your handling class:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    NSLog("Receieve stream event: %d", eventCode.rawValue);
    switch (eventCode){
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break;
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break;
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvaible");
        break;
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        NSLog("OpenCompleted");
        break;
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog("HasSpaceAvailable");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog("default reached. unknown stream event")
        break;
    }
}
```

*Note: There are some changes from raywnderlich's implementation, particularly in the delegate method.*

Comment: Could this be used to open and listen a local webserver for oauth2 loopback calls?

Comment: how to enable proxy with stream sockets?

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer for swift. My app code is swift 2 and server code is java. I had problems with swift socket but i found answer. this my problem link [how to use socket in swift (connect, send and get message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436288/how-to-use-socket-in-swift-connect-send-and-get-message) and use https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
I create own socket class this:

```
import Foundation
```

class SocketManager {

```
let socket : TCPClient

class var sharedInstance: SocketManager {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SocketManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

init() {
    // Create the socket
    self.socket = TCPClient(addr: "www.apple.com", port: 9000)
    // Connect the socket
    let (success, msg )=self.socket.connect(timeout: 1)
    print("\(msg) : \(success)")

}

internal func sendMessage(data: String){
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        let request = self.sendRequest(data, client: self.socket)
        print("received message: \(request)")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
        })

    })
}

private func sendRequest(data: String, client: TCPClient?) -> (String?) {
    // It use ufter connection
    if client != nil {
        // Send data  (WE MUST ADD SENDING MESSAGE '\n' )
        let (isSuccess, errorMessage) = client!.send(str: "\(data)\n")
        if isSuccess {
            // Read response data
            let data = client!.read(1024*10)
            if let d = data {
                // Create String from response data
                if let str = NSString(bytes: d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                    return (data: str)
                } else {
                    return (data: nil)
                }
            } else {
                return (data: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print(errorMessage)
            return (data: nil)
        }
    } else {
        return (data: nil)
    }
}
```

}

use like this:

```
SocketManager.sharedInstance.sendMessage("Salom Hammaga")
```

Comment: Can this be used for listening for data as well? Say the server sends some data in bytes, how will this class know that the data was received?

Comment: use func sendRequest() and get result data if isSuccess { } statment and you have to read data <let data = client!.read(1024*10)>

Comment: private func sendRequest(data: String, client: TCPClient?) -> (String?)  this function give you string so it is result (recieved data)