# how to use socket in swift (connect, send and get message)

Tags: swift, sockets, swift2

I am new swift. I want to make chat for iphone so i need to use client sokect. how to make this. give me advise or example  plz.
I tried this
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift
but not connected
and tried this code

```
 let client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "89.236.254.27", port: 9000)
     let (success,errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
     if success {
          let (success,errmsg) = client.send(str:"Hello World!")
          if success {
               let data = client.read(1024 * 10)
               if let d = data {
                    if let str = NSString(bytes: d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                         print(str)
                    }
               }
          } else {
               print(errmsg)
          }
     } else {
          print(errmsg)
     }
```

after change this code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
     let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
     dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
         let client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "89.236.254.27", port: 9000)
         var (success, errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
         if success {
             var (isSuccess, errorMessage) = client.send(str: "Hello!")
             if success {
                 let data = client.read(1024 * 4)
                 if let d = data {
                     if let str = NSString(bytes: d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                         print(str)
                     }
                 }
             } else {
                 print(errmsg)
             }
         } else {
             print(errmsg)
         }
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            () -> Void in
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
         })
     })
 }
```

Comment: NSStream or Third-Party API's. My favorite is [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), Im also working on a swift version myself, check it out [Swidis](https://github.com/FarhadNezhad/Swidis) (Still Beta tho)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket It is easy to use. If you will try it and will not understand some things, write comments here

Comment: alex_p thanks for answer, SwiftSocket connected but can not get recieve data. plz give me example

Comment: @AvazxonUbaydullayev I create answer below with example of my code to use this lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the `SwiftSocket` https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket for `TCP` connection. It is easy to use. For example for using it (i add comments to it):

I have my wrapper for work with this lib and this is the method how to send request and get response:

```
    private func blockingRequest(data: String, client: TCPClient?) -> (data: String?, error: ConnectionError?) {
        // It use ufter connection
        if client != nil {
            // Send data
            var (isSuccess, errorMessage) = client!.send(str: data)
            if isSuccess {
                // Read response data
                var data = client!.read(1024*10)
                if let d = data {
                    // Create String from response data
                    if let str = NSString(bytes: d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                        return (data: str, error: nil)
                    } else {
                        return (data: nil, error: ConnectionError.BadResponseData)
                    }
                } else {
                    return (data: nil, error: ConnectionError.BadResponseData)
                }
            } else {
                println(errorMessage)
                return (data: nil, error: ConnectionError.RequestError)
            }
        } else {
            return (data: nil, error: ConnectionError.RequestError)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i connected but when send data, server got message after simulator stop. why is it ?

Comment: @AvazxonUbaydullayev Can you share link to you project to see what the problem is, because it is very difficult to say something without code

Comment: alex_p, get my project this link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ShmF_Xwo0_eTNhYV83Y3dhOWs . this project shared everyone

Comment: @AvazxonUbaydullayev I looked at your project. In your folder `SocketIOClientSwift` are the files for the library `SocketIOClientSwift`, which is quite logical. But in the `WelcomeViewController` you are trying to use the objects from `SwiftSocket` lib, which files are not in the project. I removed `SocketIOClientSwift` and add `SwiftSocket` and my files looks like this: http://imagehost.spark-media.ru/i4/C33FC821-68A8-05DF-B66D-040D51B4ECFD.png With this files all works well. When `WelcomeViewController` started the `Hello!` message send to my local server and response was resived

Comment: what is 'intercom-Brigding-Header.h' ? I have not this file ? Why ?

Comment: alex_p can you give me changed project

Comment: @AvazxonUbaydullayev 'intercom-Brigding-Header.h' is automatically created when you add `SwiftSocket` files to your project. I did not do anything with the project except that just added these files. Add files from this link https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket/tree/master/SwiftSocket/ysocket to you project and it will be worked

Comment: okey, I understanded you but when i sent first time, it worked but agian send it did not work.

Comment: you will try more time sending message to server and get response message.

Comment: I share your project with button to send message to server, it works every time push it http://sharesend.com/r8cwpkpu - talker.zip

Comment: the messages written in the output stream are sent to my server only when the app is killed (stopped by xcode or killed in the iOS dock). 
Problem solved, apparently the message must finish with a "\n" to flush the output stream !

Comment: i found answer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436288/how-to-use-socket-in-swift-connect-send-and-get-message

Answer (score 0):

NSStream or Third-Party API's. My favorite is [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), Im also working on a swift version myself, check it out [Swidis](https://github.com/FarhadNezhad/Swidis) (Still Beta)

Also to mention with CocoaAsyncSocket you will need to include a [bridge-header.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)  to use as swift.